# katex math is not rendering perfectly in react

Tags: css, katex

### React code

```js
import React from "react";
import katex from "katex/dist/katex.mjs";
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: katex.renderToString("\\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}A[i]"),
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

### `/public/index.html`

**Included style**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.13.18/dist/katex.min.css" integrity="sha384-zTROYFVGOfTw7JV7KUu8udsvW2fx4lWOsCEDqhBreBwlHI4ioVRtmIvEThzJHGET" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

### Output

[image: oup-1]

### Expected output

[image: exp-op]

Can anyone tell me that what mistake is here?

Comment: Are you sure this is an issue with React?  Have you tried rendering it with plain HTML/JS?

Comment: This issue occurs also when i try with plaint html/css.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer to my question

```js
const html = katex.renderToString(str, {
    throwOnError: false,
    displayMode: true // make it true
})
```

```css
.katex-display,.katex-display > .katex, .katex-display > .katex > .katex-html {
  display: inline !important;
  // make it inline, so it can render with your text even after `displayMode:true`
}
```

```css
.katex-display{
    text-align:left !important;
}
.katex-display>.katex{
    text-align:left !important;
}
```